# Unit testing component which uses different route components

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to test the following component.

MyComponent -

```
export class MyComponent {
  radioItems: any;
  selectedItem: number = 0;
  name: string;

  constructor(private _reset: ForgotPwdService, private _router: Router) {
    if (!_reset.storedMails || !_reset.fullName) {
      _router.root.navigate(['ParentRoutePath']); // Using parent route, _router.parent.navigate() doesn't work for test either
      return;
    }
    this.name = _reset.fullName;
    this.radioItems = _reset.storedMails;
  }

  getValue(event) {
    this.selectedItem = event;
  }

  onClick() {
    this._reset.mail = this.radioItems[this.selectedItem].title;
    this._router.navigate(['RoutePath']); //Using route
  }
}
```

In the test, in `beforeEach()` method, I'm providing the following route component -`provide(ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT, {useValue: ComponentWithChildRoute})`.
But when I'm trying to run tests I'm getting the following error in the test which tries to verify the code in the constructor - `Component "ComponentWithChildRoute" has no route named "ParentRoutePath".` If I try to provide `provide(ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT, {useValue: RootRouteComponent})`, I'm getting `Component "RootRouteComponent" has no route named "RoutePath".` error in the test which runs `onClick()` method. 
Is there a way to resolve it? Maybe I can provide one of the route components in the needed tests itself, not in beforeEach()?

Code for both of the tests -

```
  it('should redirect to login when storedMails or fullName are empty',
    fakeAsync(inject([ForgotPwdService, Location, Router],
      (forgot: ForgotPwdService, location: Location, route: Router) => {
        forgot.storedMails = '';
        let mail = new NameSent(forgot, route);

        tick();

        expect(location.path()).toContain('/login');
      })
    )
  );

  it('should direct to selected item when specified',
    fakeAsync(inject([NameSent, Location], (name: NameSent, location: Location) => {
      name.onClick();

      tick();

      expect(location.path()).toContain('/mail-sent');
    }))
  );
```

### **Update:**

I managed to resolve this issue by rewriting these tests in the following way -

```
  it('should direct to selected item when specified',
    fakeAsync(inject([NameSent, Router], (name: NameSent, router: Router) => {
      spyOn(router, 'navigate');
      name.onClick();

      expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['MailSent']);
    }))
  );
```

However, I'm still interested if it is possible to somehow inject multiple route components?